# Change tab on custom UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I basically just need to change tabs when the user taps a button on my custom UIView

This is my UIView implementation

```
@implementation CustomMenuView
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        UIButton *searchButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 135.0, 40.0)];
        searchButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [searchButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        searchButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
        [searchButton setTitle:@"Search" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        searchButton.tag = 0;
        [searchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(menuItemTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self addSubview:searchButton];


    }
    return self;
}

-(void)menuItemTapped:(UIButton*)sender{
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = sender.tag;
}
```

And my ViewController class:

```
   UIView *menuView;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGFloat height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    menuView = [[CustomMenuView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 135, height)];
    [self.view addSubview:menuView];
}
```

This crashes because the UIView does not have a reference to the tabBarController. How do I call a method on my custom view's parent or what is the best approach to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deciding to use local notifications like this:

On my custom UIView

```
-(void)menuItemTapped:(UIButton*)sender{
        NSDictionary* userInfo = @{@"tab": @(sender.tag)};
        NSNotificationCenter* nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [nc postNotificationName:@"MenuItemSelected" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
```

UIViewController class

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(receiveMenuItemSelectedNotification:)
                                                     name:@"MenuItemSelected"
                                                   object:nil];
    }

    -(void) receiveMenuItemSelectedNotification:(NSNotification*)notification
    {
        if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"MenuItemSelected"])
        {
            NSDictionary* userInfo = notification.userInfo;
            NSNumber* tab = (NSNumber*)userInfo[@"tab"];
            NSLog (@"Successfully received test notification! %i", tab.intValue);
            self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = tab.intValue;

        }
    }

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"MenuItemSelected" object:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, you could use the delegate pattern here. So you create a protocol named CustomMenuViewDelegate and declare a weak property on CustomMenuView of this type. When the menuItemTapped: method is called you call a method on the CustomMenuViewDelegate property. You can make your ViewController conform to the delegate protocol and set is as the delegate in the viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Thanks I upvoted and bet this works just fine but I decided to use local notifications for this.

Comment: Sure, glad you've found a solution. Please keep in mind that using NSNotification for these things tends to be considered somewhat of an antipattern (see [this great post](https://davidnix.io/post/stop-using-nsnotificationcenter/)). Still, I guess what really matters is that it gets the job done :)